# How to provide range in Macro in Excel in below formula

Tags: excel, vbscript, macros, vba

I have to create a formula where say 3 columns are present `A`, `B` & `C` which has values till say serial 5. So now have to check If value in cell say `C1` is blank then cell `B1` would be `A1/Count(C)`.

I am able to perform this for single cell but how can use below formula for range from `A1:A5`, `B1:B5` and `C1:C5`

```
Sub CheckCnt()

Range("C6") = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("C1:C5"))

If Range("C1") = "" Then
    Range("B1") = WorksheetFunction.Round(Range("A1") / Range("C6"), 2)
Else
Range("B1") = 0

End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Placing this into a FOR loop should work.
Please see Revised code below.

```
Sub CheckCnt()
    Dim rw as Integer

Range("C6").Value = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("C1:C5"))
For rw = 1 to 5
    If Range("C" & rw).Value = "" Then
        Range("B" & rw).Value = WorksheetFunction.Round(Range("A" & rw).Value / Range("C6").Value, 2)
    Else
        Range("B" & rw).Value = 0
    End If
Next rw

End Sub
```

Let me know if this works.  Thanks so much!

Comment: Worked as expected..Thanks!

Comment: glad to hear it.  Feel free to upvote the answer so this question can be closed.  Your upvote will allow me to post comments and help more people in the future.

Comment: I tried but cn't do so, as minimum 15 reputation is required to do so and mine is 1.

Comment: oh I didnt even realize that.  Well thank you so much for trying.  Let me know if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what formula looking to insert so I've placed the ROUND formula in the range B1:B5.

B1 will be: `=ROUND($A1/$C$6,2)`
B2 will be: `=ROUND($A2/$C$6,2)`
and so on...

This code uses the R1C1 notation:

```
Sub CheckCnt()

    'Be specific about which sheet you want the result in (otherwise it will appear in the selected sheet).
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        With .Range("B1:B5")
            .FormulaR1C1 = "=Round(RC1/R6C3,2)" 'Use a formula with R1C1 notation.
            .Value = .Value 'Replace the formula with the result of the formula.
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

`RC1` means this row, column 1.  `R6C3` means row 6, column 3.
http://www.numeritas.co.uk/2013/09/the-%E2%80%98dark-art%E2%80%99-of-r1c1-notation/